# Line Height and space between paragraphs?

Tags: space-constraints

As to improve user experience, what is the standard line height for a 12 px font size?
And what is the standard space between paragraphs for 12 px (font size) body text?

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific rules for how much line-height we should actually implement on the content. This is a bit more a design decision in according to specific requirements of the content. Here are some materials that can really make you able to identify the best suited line-height for your content.

#### [line spacing__PracticalTypography](https://practicaltypography.com/line-spacing.html)

#### [Font size, line height and line width the golden ratio way__Medium](https://medium.com/@zkareemz/golden-ratio-62b3b6d4282a)

#### [Typographic Design Patterns And Best Practices__SmashingMagazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/typographic-design-survey-best-practices-from-the-best-blogs/)

#### [6 tips for better line spacing in your typography__99designs](https://99designs.com/blog/tips/6-tips-line-spacing-typography/)

#### [Why you should go big with line spacing__InvisionApp](https://www.invisionapp.com/blog/line-spacing/)

There are a tons of articles helping you out about line spacing :)